# Tweepy: Collect tweets with at least 1 word each of two lists of search words

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using Tweepy and its cursor to collect Tweets with certain search terms. My goal is to have two lists of words on two different topics, so e.g. list 1 with words about love and list 2 with words about health. I then want to search for tweets that each contain at least one word from list 1 and at least one word from list 2. My problem is that I can't even get a search running that only uses one list.

So I have the following code:

```
# extracting words from a csv-file
file_loc1 = "search_words/love.xlsx"
love_words = pd.read_excel(file_loc1, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'], usecols = "A", skiprows=11)
love_words = str(love_words['love'].values)

# converting the list to readable search terms (there are probably more elegant ways...)
love_words = love_words.lower()
love_words = love_words.replace("\r","")
love_words = love_words.replace("\n","")
love_words = love_words.replace("' '", " OR ")
love_words = love_words.replace("[", "")
love_words = love_words.replace("]", "")
love_words = love_words.replace("'", "")

search_words = love_words + " -filter:retweets"
date_since = "2020-01-01"

tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words,
              lang="en",
              since=date_since).items(5000)

tweet_text = [tweet.text for tweet in tweets]
```

So I'm retrieving the words from a csv file and put them all into a string that in the end will look like this: `word1 OR word2 OR word3 -filter:retweets`.
If it's only two or three words, it seems to work and I'm getting a lot of tweets. But if I use more terms, I don't get any tweets. It seems like maybe the OR operator is not working the way I think it is... And in the end I would like to have the search like `(love1 OR love2 OR love3 OR ...) AND (health1 OR health2 OR ...)`, so that I get tweets that contain one or more words from each of the two lists.

I hope that this explanation makes sense. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Tweepy and found the OR operator not to be sufficient. What I do is a separate search for each keyword and collect all tweets:

```
tweet_list = []
for word in keyword_list:
    tweets = api.search(word)
    tweet_list.append(tweets)
```

Then, after I have all my tweets, I filter for if they contain the words I'm interested in.

This is not efficient, nor likely to be the best solution. But it works for me.